# Mirror tables: triggers, deadlock and implicit commits

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, deadlock, autocommit

I'm have 2 similar tables, for example A and B. **I want to replicate insertions in A to B, and insertions in B to A to integrate two users systems** . I configured "after insert triggers" on each one. Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER
`after_A_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `A`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `B`
SET `id` = NEW.`id`,`name` = NEW.`name`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER
`after_B_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `B`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO `A`
SET `id` = NEW.`id`,`name` = NEW.`name`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I insert in A, the triggers calls an insert in B, but this insert executes the trigger in B and a deadlock occurs avoiding a infinite loop.

I've tried to edit triggers to DROP the another table trigger before do the INSERT and then CREATE it again after it. Example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER
`after_B_INSERT`
AFTER INSERT ON `B`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `after_A_INSERT`;
INSERT INTO `A`
SET `id` = NEW.`id`, `name` = NEW.`name`;
/* And CREATE again here */
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However CREATE is a Data Definition Language (DDL) statement that makes an implicit commit. Thus, this can't be done.

I've tried to call a PROCEDURE with the DROP inside to handle explicitly the commit, but isn't possible too.

**Any suggestion to mirror this 2 tables?**

---

UPDATE: Using [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220377/mirror-tables-triggers-deadlock-and-implicit-commits/26220565#26220565), I added a `origin` field to each table with a respective default vale `A` or `B`. Then, I alter (DROP and reCREATE) the triggers as follows:

Trigger in A:

```
...
BEGIN 
IF NEW.`origin`='A' THEN
    INSERT INTO `B`
        SET `id` = NEW.`id`, `name` = NEW.`name`,  `origin` = NEW.`origin`;
    END IF;
END
```

Trigger in B:

```
...
BEGIN 
IF NEW.`origin`='B' THEN
    INSERT INTO `A`
        SET `id` = NEW.`id`, `name` = NEW.`name`, `origin` = NEW.`origin`;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need some way to avoid creating a cycle.

I'd suggest adding a column `origin` in both tables. In table A, make the `DEFAULT 'A'`. In table B, make the `DEFAULT 'B'`.

When inserting to either table in your application, always omit the `origin` column, allowing it to take its default value.

In both triggers, replicate to the other table only if the `NEW.origin` is equal to the respective table's default.

---

Re your comment and new error:

Sorry, I forgot to mention that in the trigger when inserting to the other table, you must also copy the value of `NEW.origin`. Just in your application when you do the original insert do you omit `origin`.

Trigger in A:

```
...
BEGIN 
IF NEW.`origin`='A' THEN
    INSERT INTO `B`
        SET `id` = NEW.`id`, `name` = NEW.`name`, `origin` = NEW.`origin`;
    END IF;
END
```

Trigger in B:

```
...
BEGIN 
IF NEW.`origin`='B' THEN
    INSERT INTO `A`
        SET `id` = NEW.`id`, `name` = NEW.`name`, `origin` = NEW.`origin`;
    END IF;
END
```

I created these triggers and then tested:

```
mysql> insert into A set name = 'bill';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into B set name = 'john';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from A;
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | origin |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | bill | A      |
|  2 | john | B      |
+----+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from B;
+----+------+--------+
| id | name | origin |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | bill | A      |
|  2 | john | B      |
+----+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the dedicated time! I tested it, and works great!