# How to create a trigger the triggers a self-referencing trigger...yeah

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic, triggers

I have a MySQL database with...interesting architecture and a convoluted enrollment process. There are several program tables that need to insert rows on an historic enrollment table when they're updated, inserted or deleted. I've got that working using triggers on each of those tables (around 30 different tables) using the following iterated over all of the tables:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS programTable_afterinsert;$$
CREATE TRIGGER programTable_afterinsert AFTER INSERT ON programTable
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Enrolled = 1
            THEN
                INSERT INTO enrollment (ID, Action, Date_Updated, User, Program, Reason, Action_Date)
                    VALUES (NEW.ID, 'Enrolled', NOW(), 'programUser', 'programName', 'Enrolled in program', NOW());
        ELSEIF NEW.Enrolled = 0
            THEN
                INSERT INTO enrollment (Member_ID, Action, Date_Updated, User, Program, Reason, Action_Date)
                    VALUES (NEW.ID, 'Disenrolled', NOW(), 'programUser', 'programName', 'Disenrolled from program', NOW());
        END IF;
    END;$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS programTable_afterupdate;$$
CREATE TRIGGER programTable_afterupdate AFTER UPDATE ON programTable
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.Enrolled = 1
            THEN 
                INSERT INTO enrollment (ID, Action, Date_Updated, User, Program, Reason, Action_Date)
                    VALUES (NEW.Member_ID, 'Enrolled', NOW(), 'programUser', 'programName', 'Enrolled in program', NOW());
        ELSEIF NEW.Enrolled = 0
            THEN 
                INSERT INTO enrollment (ID, Action, Date_Updated, User, Program, Reason, Action_Date)
                    VALUES (NEW.ID, 'Disenrolled', NOW(), 'programUser', 'programName', 'Disenrolled from program', NOW());
        END IF;
    END;$$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS programTable_afterdelete;$$
CREATE TRIGGER programTable_afterdelete AFTER DELETE ON programTable
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.Enrolled = 1
            THEN 
                INSERT INTO enrollment (ID, Action, Date_Updated, User, Program, Reason, Action_Date)
                    VALUES (OLD.ID, 'Disenrolled', NOW(), 'programUser', 'programName', 'Removed from program', NOW());
        END IF;
    END;$$
```

A stripped down version of the enrollment and program tables can be created with the following:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `programTable1` (
  `ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Enrolled` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Referral_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Referral_Source` varchar(255)
);$$

CREATE TABLE `programTable2` (
  `ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Enrolled` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Referral_Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Referral_Source` varchar(255)
);$$

CREATE TABLE `enrollment` (
  `ID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Action` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `Date_Updated` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `User` varchar(12) default NULL,
  `Program` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Notes` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Reason` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Action_Date` datetime NOT NULL
);$$
```

The hurdle I'm running into is the enrollment table needs to update the program tables' enrollment when it's modified or a row is added to it. Meaning if someone is enrolled on the program table, they need to have an entry on the enrollment table for that action; if someone is enrolled via the enrollment table, they need to be updated as enrolled or disenrolled on the program table that row applies to.

The main problem is that there are two different sources people are enrolling in the programs from.

Like I said, convoluted. I know the architecture of this application isn't the best, but it's not something that can be changed.

Any ideas would be welcome! Please let me know if there anyone has questions or if any clarification is needed. I've been working on this for awhile now, so I know I'm probably leaving some stuff out of the equation due to being so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem creating triggers that update each others' tables -- as long as the triggers don't continue to insert back and forth in an infinite loop.

You need to make sure that the INSERT performed by a trigger inserts a row to the other table that will *not* result in a reciprocal action.

I wrote an example in another recent question: [Mirror tables: triggers, deadlock and implicit commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220377/mirror-tables-triggers-deadlock-and-implicit-commits/26220565#26220565)

Comment: Mr. Karwin, thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question. Your input was definitely helpful!

However, I have multiple tables that need to be synced with the enrollment table and vice versa. For the enrollment tables, through this method, it seems that I'll have to right a case statement that includes conditions for each of those tables - given that dynamic SQL can't be used in a trigger or a stored procedure used in a trigger - is there anyway around that? Or will it all need to be hard coded and updated if programs were added?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right, you can't use dynamic SQL inside a trigger, because the statement that caused the trigger to fire might be a dynamic SQL statement itself, and a single MySQL thread can't have more than one dynamic SQL handle active at the same time. You'll have to hard-code it and update the triggers every time you add a new table to mirror. Keep in mind that if this seems too inconvenient, that might be a clue that your data design that requires such bi-directional mirroring may not be a good design.

Comment: While that's unfortunate, it's not unexpected. But it's also not an option for my application due to a variety of factors. It seems like it may be time to pull this effort out of MySQL and develop it in PHP. It won't be elegant, but it should work (probably off of cron every few minutes). Now I just have to convince the programmers. /sigh Thanks again though Bill!